# How to superscript a character in a list of ng-options

Tags: angularjs, superscript, angular-chosen

I asked a question similar to this earlier, but it turned out I was approaching it wrong, so excuse that.

I have a list of items that I'm displaying to the user using [angular-chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen), some of these items have text that require part of it to be superscripted, it won't get more complicated than `m^2` or `cm^3`. I built a filter to replace the `^` character with html `<sup>`. But it turned out angular-chosen only allows `ng-options`, and you can't use html bindings in `ng-options`. Some css classes look promising but I'm not sure how to apply that to only part of the text.

So without tearing out angular-chosen, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you replace the text? Most fonts have at least characters for  ² and ³, and font stacks will (usually) ensure you can see the entire Unicode set of ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸  and ⁹.

Comment: I can yes, how would that work, with ng-options not allowing bindings?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to use html bindings in ng-options, as per Jongware's comment my only solution was to replace each instance with Unicode.